# How to escape a colon from a json object key

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I am picking data from WordPress API V2, but a certain key has a colon which breaks the operation. I am using node.js to pick specific data from what WordPress returns in its API.

Below is a json object

```
[

  {
    "id": 2873,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "some title"
    },
    "_embedded": {
      "wp:featuredmedia": [   //i want to pich this in javascript
        {
          "id": 3091,
          "date": "2018-04-18T20:51:42",
          "slug": "dr",
          "source_url": "some image url"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

i am using javascript nodejs to pick wp:featuredmedia content as below

```
app.get('/route', function (req, res) {

    var array= [];
    var url = 'url';
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            body.forEach(function (item) {

                array.push({
                    picture: item._embedded.wp:featuredmedia  //error is here
            });
            });

            res.send(array);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Try to use [] property accessors rather than dot accessors like **item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets `[]` property accessors

```
app.get('/route', function (req, res) {

    var array= [];
    var url = 'url';
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            body.forEach(function (item) {

                array.push({
                    picture: item._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"]
            });
            });

            res.send(array);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Prateek Its working but i want to go inside now and pick only source_url. how can i do that? check that json there is source_url and its what i want to pick. thanks

Comment: Ok thanks i got it. its picture: item._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].source_url